# Laptop sleep bug

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep, wake-up

I got a new laptop a few months ago and I have noticed a bug with it. If you are using the laptop and then all of a sudden you close it really quickly, then the light stays on saying that it is on, but when you open it the screen stays off like it is in sleep mode. After a few minutes, the laptop shuts off and when I boot it back up it says that the laptop has went into a error. The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite, and it runs windows 8.

Comment: Close it slower!

Comment: It really happens when other people use it. They SLAM it down!

Comment: This seems like a hardware fault, or a staffing issue... I assume it remains in sleep mode even if you press keys/move mouse etc?

Comment: I can't do anything to get it back up except shut it down.

Comment: I would contact Toshiba I'm afraid, I have no ideas really! Sorry.

Comment: No problem, I didn't expect a real answer anyways....

Comment: Does putting it to sleep normally (i.e. using the sleep button or from Windows UI) work as expected?

Comment: @ernie Yes, it works.

Comment: So if you close it quickly, and wait, does it eventually go to sleep?  What happens if you close it slowly?  My guess would be that you're trying to wake it before it's fully gone to sleep, and that puts it in a weird state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the issue. The power system that I have been using (eco by Toshiba) had a bug in the sleep function that throws a error when it is about to go to sleep and as the machine is figuring out the issue, someone opens it and puts it in a weird state of trying to fix the issue, and someone opening, and then shuts down the machine for critical error. I switched my power plan and it has been working ever since.